# Validate Input AspNetMvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How do I validate the Exit of an Input, already have the function that returns bool, if returning false, is not allowed to exit the input seller.sname, and present an alert message.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Update">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="seller.sellerid" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input asp-for="seller.name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">EMail:</label>
            <input asp-for="seller.email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="birthdate">Birth Date:</label>
            <input asp-for="seller.birthdate" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="basesalary">Base Salary:</label>
            <input asp-for="seller.basesalary" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="departamentid">Departament:</label>
            <select asp-for="seller.departamentid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.departaments, "departamentid", "name"));" class="form-control"> </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            <a asp-action="Index">Back To List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell specifically which input you want to validate and also include your present controller method code.

Comment: Just use attributes on your model. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: use [Required] on Model property which you want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your inputs using model classes by adding attributes/data annotation to the properties. 
Or
Other way is to validate your inputs using javascript or jquery.

if you mean by "Exit the input" as on blur , then add an event and bind it to onblur in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

add this jquery code in your view

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='sellerName']").bind('focusout', function(e) {
        if(CheckSellerNameFunc()==false) {
            $("#alertMessage").css("display","block")
            e.preventDefault();               
        }
        else{
        $("#alertMessage").hide()
        }
    });
});

var CheckSellerNameFunc=function(){
//your function business
//example
var i=1;
if(i==1){return false}
else{ return true}
}
```

You have to make these changes in html code :

```
            <input asp-for="seller.name" name="sellerName" class="form-control" />
            <span id="alertMessage">please fill textbox</span>
```

and you can test it from this link :

https://jsfiddle.net/zw5ax0vh/3/

Hope it was helpful

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has very nice input validation built in, no need to reinvent the wheel. For starters, this validation is client side only, which can be disabled by the caller, allowing them to send invalid values.

Comment: we want client side validation no server side!

Comment: No, you definitely want serverside validation.

Comment: Please be careful with the question. """How do I validate the Exit of an Input ... if returning false, is not allowed to exit the input seller.sname"""

Answer (score 0):

First add validation attributes to your model:

```cs
public SellerModel Seller {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must be a string with a minimum length of {2} and a maximum length of {1}.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //....
}
```

*btw, it is a common practice to apply [PascalCasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for classes and properties*

then on the view side add validation for each input:

```
<form asp-action="Update">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Seller.SellerId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Seller.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Seller.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Seller.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Seller.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Seller.Email" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Seller.Email" class="text-danger"></span>

    .....

</form>
```

Finally to enable client side validation add the validation partial that already exists in the default template:

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

if you are not using the default template you can create a validation partial that includes the validation libraries:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi guys, Tks for your help. 
I found documentation for what I need, it's called RemoteValidation on Asp.Net. I create the function in my backend layer, and in my attribute class I call the parameter [Remote (action: "MyFunction", controller: "MyController")]